# Cant open Reports on SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, business-intelligence

My friend sent me a report project via email, i can open the file but not the .rdl file due to "Could not find a part of the path  C://Users.." ?

Has it anything to do with his permission settings ?

Comment: But you have the rdl file right? you just cannot open it with ssrs? Or you have the name in your project but not the file. Try to edit the file and look after the path and fix it. Notepad is good for that

Answer (score 0):

No that does not have anything to do with permissions. Either the .rdl file is not existing anymore where it is supposed to be or it is included but cannot be found because of an absulute path in the solution file.

If the rdl file is physically existing in the folder, try to remove it from the report solution and re-add as existing item to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend has to send you the report files (*.rdl), too. Copy them into the the folder of your project:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3311058/report_files.png

Open the report project in your Visual Studio again.